# Desligar o microfone do headset

Tags: android, shell

Quero força o dispositivo usar o próprio microfone, não o do headset 
Tentei usar o comando "android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" no shell mas acho que estou usando ele errado.

Alguém pode me ajudar

Observação tenho root .

Comment: Isso é dentro da sua aplicação?

Comment: Isso não é um comando, é uma constante do android. Quando você a utiliza em um `BroadcastReceiver`, o android te notifica toda vez que o usuário plugar ou desplugar o headset. Utilize a biblioteca [AudioManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

Comment: Me corrija se eu estiver errado, para usar uma constante preciso usar uma classe antes ?

Comment: Sou muito novo em programação só sei ler em Java e nem é lá essas coisas, queria fazer uma função em um aplicativo (tasker) today vez que coloco o fone ele automaticamente desliga o microfone do headset é liga o do aparelho

Comment: Não tem nenhum tipo de comando tipo esse (settings put global low_power 0) para desligar o microfone do headset?  Vou ter que escrever um código inteiro para isso ?